# zipalign: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android/libbacktrace.so.0: undefined symbol: _ZN11unwindstack12ElfInterfaceD2Ev

Tags: android

Today i install kali 2020.4, and then i install zipalign and Getting this error while using zipalign.

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install zipalign
root@kali:~# zipalign 
zipalign: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android/libbacktrace.so.0: undefined symbol: _ZN11unwindstack12ElfInterfaceD2Ev
```

I update and upgrade my kali:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

and install latest version of adb package:

```
apt-get install adb android-libadb
```

and install the android-libadb and android-libbacktrace

```
apt-get install android-libadb
apt-get install android-libbacktrace
```

But this problem still exists!

Comment: Seems to be known bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=977023

Answer (score 1):

Finally i find a solution!
i delete the libbacktrace.so.0 file:

```
    cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android
    rm libbacktrace.so.0
```

and download the new one from:

```
    https://packages.debian.org/buster/android-libbacktrace
```

you must to download amd64 Architecture from the list. and Extract it:
[image]

```
    mkdir android-libbacktrace
    dpkg-deb -R THE_FILE_YOU_DOWNLOADED android-libbacktrace
```

and move the new file to to android directory:

```
    cd android-libbacktrace/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android
    cp libbacktrace.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android
```

now run zipalign command. yes we do it!

Comment: many thanks, this worked for me too!