# how to fix error zipalign: symbol lookup error: zipalign: undefined symbol: _ZN11zip_archive7InflateERKNS_6ReaderEjjPNS_6WriterEPm

Tags: security, reverse-engineer, apk

I installed `zipalign` in kali linux but when i run the command i got the error:

```
zipalign: symbol lookup error: zipalign: undefined symbol:   
_ZN11zip_archive7InflateERKNS_6ReaderEjjPNS_6WriterEPm
```

Comment: Have you update the libraries from which `zipalign`  depend? And why Kali, have you try Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, i tried both OS Ubuntu and Kali and i got the same error

Comment: In such case you should report a bug.

Comment: Does [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1614228/zipalign-symbol-lookup-error-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-android-libbacktrace-so) help ?

Comment: @harrymc no i did what is in this post but the error message not the same. So it did not work for me